# Spark storage memory allocation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, memory-management

I am trying to run a spark job with the following config: `spark.driver.memory=1g`

I am submitting the job in spark running on k8s cluster and in a local spark cluster (spark running in mac OS).
The storage memory allocated in EKS is 366.3MiB whereas in local cluster it is 434.4MiB.

Can someone explain to me what is causing this difference when running spark in K8s cluster versus local cluster?

Note: spark.memory.fraction and spark.memory.storageFraction is the same for both environments.
spark.memory.fraction=0.6
spark.memory.storageFraction=0.5

I tried submitting the same job in K8s and local cluster.

I want to understand the calculation behind the storage memory in both environments.